# Showing date modified of a separate excel document in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I have an excel that is pulling data from another excel via a simple range copy formula, however I was wondering if it is possible to also pull the date & time that the source excel was last modified and put it into a cell in the target excel.

Through research, I found out about the FILEDATETIME function, however I'm not sure if this would work for what I'm trying to do.

Any help would be super appreciated!  Thank you so much!!

Comment: Yes thats exactly what you need to get the last modified date of the file you pull from. But without any code no idea how this will fit with what you're already doing. `FileDateTime("C:\Example.xls")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject, f As File '<-- reference: Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set f = fso.GetFile(mySourceWorkbook.FullName)

Debug.Print f.DateCreated f.DateLastAccessed f.DateLastModified
' And you can get much more information about the file
```

Comment: Hi A.S.H. thanks for your response!  Sorry, I'm a little new to VBA/Macros, where in the code would I put the specific cell that I would like the information to print into?  (sorry if that's a stupid question)    Also, when I try to run it, it says, Compile error: User-defined type not defined, and it highlights : "fso As FileSystemObject"

Comment: you should add a reference to the VBA project: `Tools->References->Check Microsoft Scripting Runtime`. Then to write the file's name to a cell, for example in cell A1: `Range("A1").Value = f.DateLastModified`